# swift3 Core data fetch crash

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data

I am inserting data into a table, its insert successfully,

but when I fetch all data then its fetch successful array of entity,

but when I use entity then I check nil of entity. The attribute is String type, when I do "Entity.attributeName"  app is crash while I am using option var to store attribute value.

> Error is "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException"

I do not understand why its crash while I check already check the entity object

Please suggest me how I can debug and handle this type of exception in swift3.

```
 /// fetch method to Fetch data 

func fetchRecordsForEntity(_ entity: String, inManagedObjectContext managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) -> [NSManagedObject] {
        // Create Fetch Request
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entity)
        fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        // Helpers
        var result = [NSManagedObject]()

        do {
            // Execute Fetch Request
            let records = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

            if let records = records as? [CityEntity] {
                result = records
            }

        } catch {
            print("Unable to fetch managed objects for entity \(entity).")
        }

        return result
    }


/// where app crash
  let cityEntity:CityEntity? = self.allCity![indexPath.row]
             let cityName:String? = cityEntity?.cn_city_name
```

Comment: Put some code here

Comment: If you data should be populate the `tableView`? If so, you can use `NSFetchedResultsController` instead.